# Dropdown auto select for page to page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, drop-down-menu

How can I auto select from drop down.

Like where customer/reserve.php then click the dropdown and goes to customer/reserve_time&date.php

I'm comfortable using PHP if there's any tutorials can you link it to me

I search in Google but not a single one comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wants to redirect to another page whenever user changes dropdown value. So, you can do a javascript function call on dropdown change event.

```
<select name="dropdown" onchange="redirectPage(this.value);">
  <option value="url1">Option A</option>
  <option value="url2">Option B</option>
</select>
```

Your javascript function starts here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectPage(value)
{
 window.location.href = value;
}
</script>
```

**Note:** url1 and url2 are the link for the pages. Try This...

Answer (score 1):

You need get in the second page the value selected for the user at the first page.

If you are using GET

```
$value = $_GET['param'];
```

If you are using POST

```
$value = $_POST['param'];
```

-

```
<select>
 <option value="foo" <?php if($value=="foo") echo "selected"; ?>>bar</option>
 <option value="foo1" <?php if($value=="foo1") echo "selected"; ?>>bar2</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:** Change page and pass parameter when select option.

```
<select onchange="window.location.href='other.php?value=' + this.value">
  <option value="">-- Select one --</option>
  <option value="men">Men</option>
  <option value="woman">Woman</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i just want to ask where i can put the reserve.php and the reserve_time&date.php ..

Comment: like you have 2 select : the regular and special... when you select the special it goes to the other page..

Comment: Do you need to change page when an user select a dropdown option?

Comment: yes, when the user select a dropdown option it goes to another page